# Someone that can work on all OSs

Tags: single-word-requests

In my [CV](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/cv/), I have a line that says:

> OSs: Windows, Mac OS X and Linux

Is there a word <sub>(that a human could understand)</sub> that laconically says that I am able to work on all OSs?

---

Example:

George is able to work on all operating systems, i.e. Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Find X so that one could say:

George is X. // or something like that

Comment: Do you differentiate between having the capacity to work on all of them if you were to learn them and having experience with all of them?  Have you worked on AIX, VxWorks, ThreadX, FreeRTOS, LynxOS, minix, EmBOS, Vax VMS...?

Comment: I suspect someone will flag this as a "single word request without context". The question would be a little clearer if you gave an example sentence.

Comment: @Jim I haven't worked in all flavors of Ubuntu for example. However, I have worked with all three OSs, but going into details on the flavors is not my cup of tea (it that's what you are asking). Benjamin thanks, I saw that in the tag, but I thought what I had was enough, updated!

Comment: @gsamaras- No, those are not flavors of Linux, they are all different operating systems apart from the "Big Three"  The point is: You can't use the word ***all*** if you just mean, Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

Comment: The first term that I think of is *cross-platform developer*. However, this might be interpreted as "can write a single piece of software that runs on multiple platforms" instead of your desired definition "can write a piece of software that runs on any given platform". Not sure how important this distinction is.

Comment: @Jim I thought so, that's why I asked. Well I didn't even know the existed, so no I would like to keep in the Big Three range (and probably the person who is going to read my CV also knows only these three, so I would say that we can assume to "all"). Oh OK, now I saw your edit..

Comment: Don't limit yourself to a single word. two or three words might be the better option in the end.

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall I am not either. As you see I am far from an experienced person like you. However what I wanted to state is that yes, I can write code that would run on all 3 OSs, but also that I am confident to use any of these three machines in the office for example (but wouldn't that be obvious?). Mitch, what do you have in mind?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: @MετάEd daccord :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One that comes to mind is **multi-platform**:

> **[multi-platform](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/multiplatform?q=multi-platform)** *adjective*
>
> Compatible with or involving more than one type of computer or operating system

*Source: Oxford Dictionaries Online*

(You'd probably have to modify it a bit: *OSs: Multiple* or *I can work with multiple platforms.*)

Bear in mind, though, I see nothing wrong with simply listing those three OSs as you have done.